# Is it possible to call a function using a function pointer with number and type of arguments known only at runtime

Tags: c, function-pointers

Background : I am creating a library to allow a process to call another function from another process using IPC.

Each process needs to register its functions with:

```
void register_function(char* function_name, 
                       void(*func)(), 
                       int nb_parameters, 
                       const int parameters_type[])
```

My problem is when I need to actually call the function after it was requested through the IPC, I cannot call the function because the number and types of parameters is known only at runtime.

I am thinking about calling the function using a struct created dynamically but I'm not sure about the order of arguments I should use or even if it is a good idea.

Any idea ?

Comment: It is certainly possible to do manually in assembler, as long as you know (or can detect) the calling convention used by the function.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to do it manually.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I know how to hack this together in MSVC (without resorting to assembler), but this wouldn't be portable in any case.

Comment: I'm using gcc and in my case it is under an ARM architecture.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use two arguments:

1st argument type: (int). Meaning -> number of arguments

2nd argument type: (void*) -> list with so many arguments as indicated by the 1st argument.

Just like argc and argv in main.

Best regards.

Comment: And how does this keep the types of the arguments?